# I am doing Inventory system in unity but its giving me these errors. What should i do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi im begginer of C# and unity and i am doing inventory items moving and it gave mi these 3 errors:
**error CS1061: 'MouseItemData' does not contain a definition for 'InventorySlot' and no accessible extension method 'InventorySlot' accepting a first argument of type 'MouseItemData' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

**error CS0103: The name 'clickedUIslot' does not exist in the current context**

**error CS1061: 'InventorySlot' does not contain a definition for 'AssignItem' and no accessible extension method 'AssignItem' accepting a first argument of type 'InventorySlot' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**
I dont really understand what i need to do so here is my code:
Inventory Display:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public abstract class InventoryDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] MouseItemData mouseInventoryItem;

    protected InventorySystem inventorySystem;
    protected Dictionary<InventorySlot_UI, InventorySlot> slotDictionary;

    public InventorySystem InventorySystem => inventorySystem;
    public Dictionary<InventorySlot_UI, InventorySlot> SlotDictionary => slotDictionary;

    protected virtual void Start()
    {

}

    public abstract void AssignSlot(InventorySystem invToDisplay);

    protected virtual void UpdateSlot(InventorySlot updatedSlot)
    {
        foreach (var slot in SlotDictionary)
        {
            if (slot.Value == updatedSlot) // Slot value - the "under the hood" inventory slot.
            {
                slot.Key.UpdateUISlot(updatedSlot); // Slot key - the UI representation of the value.
            }
        }
    }

    public void SlotClicked(InventorySlot_UI clickedUISlot)
    {

        // Clicked slot has an item - mouse doesn't have an item - pick up that item.

        if (clickedUISlot.AssignedInventorySlot.ItemData != null && mouseInventoryItem.InventorySlot.ItemData == null)
    {
            // If player is holding shift key? Split the stack.

            mouseInventoryItem.UpdateMouseSlot(clickedUISlot.AssignedInventorySlot);
            clickedUIslot.ClearSlot();
            return;
    }

        //Clicked slot does not have an item - Mouse does have an item - place the mouse item into the empty slot.

        // Both slots have an item - decide what to do...
        // Are both items the same? If so combine them.
        //Is the slot stack size + mouse stack size > the slot Max Stack Size? If so, take from          mouse.
        // If different items, then swap the items.
    } 

}
```

MouseItemData:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class MouseItemData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image ItemSprite;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ItemCount;
    public InventorySlot AssignedInventorySlot;

    private void Awake()
    {
        ItemSprite.color = Color.clear;
        ItemCount.text = "";
    }

    public void UpdateMouseSlot(InventorySlot invSlot)
    {
        AssignedInventorySlot.AssignItem(invSlot);
        ItemSprite.sprite = invSlot.ItemData.Icon;
        ItemCount.text = invSlot.StackSize.ToString();
        ItemSprite.color = Color.white;
    }
}
```

And i added some lines of code to InventorySlot:

```
public void AssignedItem(InventorySlot invSlot)
{
    if (itemData == invSlot.ItemData) AddToStack(invSlot.stackSize);
    else
    {
        itemData = invSlot.itemData;
        stackSize = 0;
        AddToStack(invSlot.stackSize);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help please? I would be really happy.

I tried to check my code by youtube tutorial but it seems to be OK, i think i did not notice something. It have to enable players to move items through inventory but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

> 'InventorySlot' does not contain a definition for 'AssignItem'

The function you've included from **InventorySlot** is named **AssignedItem**, which explains that.
This can be fixed by changing the call to the function to `AssignedInventorySlot.AssignedItem(invSlot);`

> MouseItemData' does not contain a definition for 'InventorySlot'

You named the **InventorySlot** variable **AssignedInventorySlot** in **MouseItemData**.

This variable doesn't exist: `mouseInventoryItem.InventorySlot`.
In your `MouseItemData` class you have a variable named `AssignedInventorySlot` of type `InventorySlot`.
Instead you should write `mouseInventory.AssignedInventorySlot`.

You should look into setting up your IDE with Unity Intellisense, since these errors should be highlighted.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply and could you tell me how to fix it to make it work?

Comment: If you can please tell me i dont know What to do, im trying to figure it out over 3 days and i still didnt make any progress.